# Google Big Query - loading a csv file - Error while reading table

Tags: google-bigquery, parsing-error

I'm trying to upload a report in CSV fotmat to Google Big Query.
The report contains the following column names:

> Adjustment Type; Day; Country; Asset ID; Asset Title; Asset Labels; Asset
>   Channel ID; Asset Type; Custom ID; TMS; EIDR; UPC; Season; Episode
>   Title; Episode Number; Director; Studio; Owned Views; YouTube Revenue Split
>   : Auction; YouTube Revenue Split : Reserved; YouTube Revenue Split :
>   Partner Sold YouTube Served; YouTube Revenue Split : Partner Sold
>   Partner Served; YouTube Revenue Split; Partner Revenue : Auction; Partner
>   Revenue : Reserved; Partner Revenue : Partner Sold YouTube
>   Served; Partner Revenue : Partner Sold Partner Served; Partner Revenue

After creating the table for this report, the column names and types look as follows:

```
[
 {
   "name": "Adjustment_Type",
   "type": "STRING"
 },
 {
   "name": "Day",
   "type": "STRING"
 },
 {
   "name": "Country",
   "type": "STRING"
 },
 {
   "name": "Asset_ID",
   "type": "STRING"
 },
 {
   "name": "Asset_Title",
   "type": "STRING"
 },
 {
   "name": "Asset_Labels",
   "type": "STRING"
 },
 {
   "name": "Asset_Channel_ID",
   "type": "STRING"
 },
 {
   "name": "Asset_Type",
   "type": "STRING"
 },
 {
   "name": "Custom_ID",
   "type": "STRING"
 },
 {
   "name": "TMS",
   "type": "STRING"
 },
 {
   "name": "EIDR",
   "type": "STRING"
 },
 {
   "name": "UPC",
   "type": "STRING"
 },
 {
   "name": "Season",
   "type": "STRING"
 },
 {
   "name": "Episode_Title",
   "type": "STRING"
 },
 {
   "name": "Episode_Number",
   "type": "STRING"
 },
 {
   "name": "Director",
   "type": "STRING"
 },
 {
   "name": "Studio",
   "type": "STRING"
 },
 {
   "name": "Owned_Views",
   "type": "STRING"
 },
 {
   "name": "YouTube_Revenue_Split___Auction",
   "type": "FLOAT"
 },
 {
   "name": "YouTube_Revenue_Split___Reserved",
   "type": "FLOAT"
 },
 {
   "name": "YouTube_Revenue_Split___Partner_Sold_YouTube_Served",
   "type": "FLOAT"
 },
 {
   "name": "YouTube_Revenue_Split___Partner_Sold_Partner_Served",
   "type": "FLOAT"
 },
 {
   "name": "YouTube_Revenue_Split",
   "type": "FLOAT"
 },
 {
   "name": "Partner_Revenue___Auction",
   "type": "FLOAT"
 },
 {
   "name": "Partner_Revenue___Reserved",
   "type": "FLOAT"
 },
 {
   "name": "Partner_Revenue___Partner_Sold_YouTube_Served",
   "type": "FLOAT"
 },
 {
   "name": "Partner_Revenue___Partner_Sold_Partner_Served",
   "type": "FLOAT"
 },
 {
   "name": "Partner_Revenue",
   "type": "FLOAT"
 }
]
```

While trying to query the table, I'm getting the following error message:

> Could not parse 'YouTube Revenue Split : Auction' as double for field
>   YouTube_Revenue_Split___Auction (position 18) starting at location 0
>   (error code: invalid)

Any idea, what could be the reason for this error?

Comment: Does the error appear when trying to import the CSV or after it's imported and you try to query the table? Can you give  an example of `YouTube Revenue Split : Auction'` value?

Comment: The error appears after the csv is imported and when I try to query the table. An example would be: 455.370646

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been able to replicate the error. In my case it appears when trying to load the CSV to BigQuery. The CSV has the `string` `YouTube Revenue Split : Auction` where  should be `float`.

What I suspect is happening is that your CSV file has the column headers in it and you are not skipping them when loading the file to BigQuery. This causes that, when the import process gets to the `YouTube_Revenue_Split___Auction` field (position 18), expects to insert `float`, but instead it tries to insert the column header, `YouTube Revenue Split : Auction`, which is a `string` that cannot be parsed correctly.

Try re-loading the CSV but remove the headers first (or skip them using the `Header rows to skip` option).

If my supossition is wrong and this doesn't apply, update your question by adding the query that produces the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot Guillermo, it works! Indeed, the csv file has headers, I have just skipped 1 row and it's working fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to what Guillermo said, you can also have Big Query automatically identify the headers and field types when you upload your files in CSV

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and solved it by replacing the semi-colons with commas.

You can use a regex for this or use this great online text replacement tool that I found - https://onlinetexttools.com/replace-text